# Power loss, hard drive missing on next reboot (?!)

Tags: debian, ext4, data-recovery, fsck

There was a power failure earlier today, and now my system won't boot anymore. It shows the following error message and drops me to a root shell to try and recover the data for myself:

```
Log of fsck -C -R -A -a
Sat Jul 30 12:56:49 2016

fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
fsck.ext4: No such file or diretory while trying to open /dev/sdc1
Possibly non-existent device?
/dev/sdb3: clean, 3040/61054976 files, 178253587/244189696 blocks
fsck died with exit status 8

Sat Jul 30 12:56:49 2016
```

`/dev/sdc` is my storage hard drive. I checked in the BIOS and it is still detected there. But when Debian boots and drops me to the shell, I can't find `/dev/sdc` anywhere, let alone `/dev/sdc1`.

Is there any hope at all to recover my data? It's mostly things I can re-download, but it also had a few virtual machines and their backups.

I'm not sure where to take it from there. I would `fsck` the partition but I can't see it at all, it's like `/dev/sdc` doesn't even exist anymore and the drive isn't plugged in as far as Debian is concerned.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you see it in `lsblk`?  Did the device name perhaps change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did:

Boot the machine with a `sysrescuecd` LiveCD and check the devices with `fdisk -l`.

There, I could see that `sda` was the SSD system disk, and `sdb` was the 1TB storage disk. So my assumptions were wrong, I thought the storage disk was `sdc`.

Then I mounted `/dev/sda1` which is the system partition. I went to check `/etc/fstab` and noticed there was a `/dev/sdc1` to be mounted at `/backup`. I'm not sure why that was, maybe a misconfiguration a while ago. This machine hadn't restarted in over 4 months, so I guess I didn't notice until now.

`/dev/sdc` was indeed not present in the system. So I removed it from `/etc/fstab`, unmounted `/dev/sda1` and restarted.

Everything went fine then. Debian was freaking out because it was being told to mount `/dev/sdc1` at `/backup` but it couldn't find that device, which had long been disconnected from the machine.

As usual, the computer was right and the human was wrong!

Comment: Glad to know it now work ! please accept your own answer as accepted to close the loop of the question

Comment: I can't just yet, it says to wait 22 more hours.